# FXCop rule Interface methods should be callable by child types

Tags: interface, fxcop

When running FxCop I get the error that interface methods should be callable by child types.

The resolution states the following:

"Make 'MenuPreview' sealed (a breaking change if  this class has previously shipped), 
  implement the method non-explicitly, or implement a new method that exposes 
  the functionality of 'IComponentConnector.Connect(int, object)' 
  and is visible to derived classes."

I get this for all classes the derive from Window or some other UI class.  Is this a red herring that I can ignore, or is there something I should be doing?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that if an interface is implemented explicitly, it will be impossible for a derived class to both change the interface behavior and make use of the base-class behavior.  A common pattern to get around this difficulty in cases where explicit interface implementation would be required is to have the interface do nothing but call a protected virtual method, and have any derived classes that wish to override the behavior of the interface do so by means of the protected virtual method.

Consider IDisposable.Dispose().  If the code in an explicit implementation were actually responsible for performing the disposal, there would be no way for a derived class to add its own dispose logic except by reimplementing IDisposable, and there would be no way for a class which reimplemented IDisposable to access its parent's Dispose method.  Although Microsoft could have had IDisposable.Dispose call a protected function with a different name, it opted to use the same name but add a dummy parameter of type Boolean.